# Alfresco Repository failed to start with `CONTENT INTEGRITY ERROR`

Tags: alfresco

I just deployed Alfresco community last version using Its official docker compose file. the content services fails to start. this is the related logs :

```
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 08:22:27,267  WARN  [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] The 'dir.root' property is set to a relative path './alf_data'.  'dir.root' should be overridden to point to a specific folder.
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 08:22:27,267  INFO  [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] The root data directory ('dir.root') is: ./alf_data
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 08:22:27,282  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] CONTENT INTEGRITY ERROR: System content not found in content store: 'store://2020/4/27/6/51/f4d50bf1-e33a-4d06-8c58-6d09ced6a4db.bin'
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 08:22:27,282  ERROR [repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker] [localhost-startStop-1] Ensure that the 'dir.root' property './alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location.
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 08:22:27,288  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
alfresco_1               | org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03270018 Ensure that the 'dir.root' property './alf_data' is pointing to the correct data location.
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:212)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.access$0(ConfigurationChecker.java:167)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1$1.doWork(ConfigurationChecker.java:155)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:602)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker$1.execute(ConfigurationChecker.java:151)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:338)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.admin.ConfigurationChecker.onBootstrap(ConfigurationChecker.java:161)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:56)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:221)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:186)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:206)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:402)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:896)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
alfresco_1               |  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
alfresco_1               |  at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:129)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:150)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:140)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:717)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
alfresco_1               |  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
alfresco_1               |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
alfresco_1               | 27-Apr-2020 08:22:27.292 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
alfresco_1               | 27-Apr-2020 08:22:27.298 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors
```

when I remove all docker volumes and start docker and deploy Alfresco it works fine, but after I stop the containers and re-run I get this error again.

what is the problem?

Comment: Did you ensure that your alf data directory is on a persisted volume? Looks like it might be being discarded between runs

Comment: you are right, there was no volume in Alfresco container. now I have another problem, in the system that I run the alfresco, there is a rabbitmq instance running. I changed activemq ports in docker-compose file but the content service get stucks in "Starting 'Messaging' subsystem, ID: [Messaging, default]".